# How to retrieve Google-talk user's id

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

Dose anyone know, how to retrieve kind of Google-talk user's id bellow of contact list?

```
xxxxx@public.talk.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Talk between two users via hangouts (hangouts.google.com). This will "create" id@public.talk.google.com in roster's list of each user.

Then use Adium as Gtalk client, setup credentials for user which will be "sender" of your message.

Sign in via Adium and you will see in contact list id@public.talk.google.com of receiver.

**Shortcut answer**:

1) sender talks to receiver via hangouts

2) Use Adium for sender

3) read receiver id@public.talk.google.com in sender's contact list in Adium